# Pass variable to spawn

Tags: shell, scripting, expect

I want to pass server name which is listed in a file (servers_list) as variable to spawn command which is in another script (user_create_script). Purpose of this script is to create user(david) in multiple servers.

```
#cat servers_list
server1
server2
server3


#cat user_create_script
    spawn ssh -t user@$i sudo /usr/sbin/useradd david
    expect "password:"
    send "pass123\r"
    interact
```

Comment: would you please read this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187339/spawn-command-not-found

Comment: @Goro, thanks alot. Given link is very helpful. My Problem solved. Thanks aton

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have
 user_create_script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set fh [open servers_list r]
while {[gets $fh server_name] != -1} {
    spawn ssh -t user@$server_name sudo /usr/sbin/useradd david
    expect "password:"
    send "pass123\r"
    expect eof
}
close $fh
```

I assume your remote user does not require a password for sudo.

More documentation about Tcl (upon which expect is built), including tutorials, is here: https://tcl.tk/doc/